# Recyclerview not all data is displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hi I am trying to display data in a recyclerview in android by parsing a json from mysql database. But it keeps displaying just some of the data and I can't seem to find the problem.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Course> data;
private Context context;
public Adapter(Context context,List<Course> data){
    this.data=data;
    this.context=context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.course_list,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Course current=data.get(position);
    holder.tCoursecode.setText(current.getmCoursecode());
    holder.tCoursetitle.setText(current.getmCoursetitle());
    holder.tCredit.setText(String.valueOf(current.getmCredit()));
    holder.tMarks.setText(form.format (current.getmMarks()));
    holder.tGrade.setText(current.getmGrade());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   TextView tCoursecode;
    TextView tCoursetitle;
    TextView tCredit;
    TextView tMarks;
    TextView tGrade;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tCoursecode=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tcc);
        tCoursetitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tct);
        tCredit=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tc);
        tMarks=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tm);
        tGrade=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tg);
    }
}
```

this the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/right">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tcc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="CSC 460" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tct"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text= "Information Security"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="78.4"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="A"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:the grade "A" is not displaying

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwd8.jpg)

Comment: I think the horizontal space is not enough to display the "grade", try remove your `android:padding`s to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tcc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="CSC 460"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="Information Security"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="78.4"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="A"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

hope this helps